# Как правильно использовать комбинацию ThreadPool и PySpark для записи в одну таблицу?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, apache-spark, pyspark, spark

У меня есть набор табличек (более тысячи), в каждой из которых одна колонка ('date') содержит только одно значение, но для разных таблиц это значение разное (как для партицирования).

Все эти файлы я хочу склеить в одну таблицу, но в цикле делать append очень долго.
Идея в использовании конструкции вида:

```
def write_chunk(table_name):
    (
        spark.table(table_name)
        .join(...)
        .filter(...)
        .write.partitionBy('date').mode('append').format('parquet').saveAsTable('new_tn')
    )

pool = ThreadPool(16)

with tqdm(total=len(dates)) as pbar:
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(write_chunk, dates):
        pbar.update()
```

Конечно, в конфиге используется опция для безопасной записи

```
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
```

Однако, при этом спарк ругается на невозможность переименования готовой таблицы из tmp формата в итоговый.

Есть ли возможность параллельно писать в одну таблицу спарком, и как это правильно делать (если возможно)?

PS: union на таком количестве таблиц не отрабатывает

Comment: Так то Спарк больше для выборки данных, а не для записи. А сами таблички эти большие? И главное - зачем вы это всё делаете, какова цель этого процесса? Что склеить таблички я понял - но для чего это делается?

Comment: @CrazyElf, таблички могут достигать в весе нескольких гигабайт. Изначально имелась очень большая табличка (настолько, что я могу работать в спарке единомоментно только с одной партицией), партицированная по дате. Из этой таблицы мне нужно сформировать еще одну с добавлением некоторых фильтров и преобразований. Можно было решать ее поочередной работой с партициями и appendом в единую таблу, но я решил ускорить это дело, обрабатывая партиции в разных потоках (записать в разные таблы, а потом их объединить, но на последнем этапе вышла не)

Comment: Ну не знаю как в данном случае, но обычно лучше всё-таки самому спарку отдавать решение, где ему в много потоков работать, а где в один. Там же вся суть в том, что ему обычно дают много памяти и ресурсов и он сам как-то там у себя данные колбасит через мап-редьюс. Я не уверен, что это в целом хорошая идея обращаться к спарку в много потоков. У него просто память и очереди забьются и он будет менее эффективно работать.